# SEO for AngularJS hosted at github pages

Tags: angularjs, seo, github-pages

Is there any way to set up SEO for websites hosted on github? I've been watching as the prerender.io solutions, but it seems that these solutions imply a backend server configuration. So I'm here to ask if there is another solution that does not require backend configuration.

Comment: Have you tried SEO.js? As they say, they provide "**1)server-side integration** that you need to install on your server and the **2)snapshot service** at getseojs.com". I think you are looking to the snapshot service. Hope it help

Comment: Look at this also https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Answer (score 1):

Man, to set up SEO for ANGULAR.JS, u will need to setup web server to deliver a snapshot page instead the angular.js page when user agent is a bot or have query string _scaped... 
. And today we can't in github pages...